# How does Nathan's "poor man’s lamb" parable relate to David's deeds?

Tags: nevua-prophecy, king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of, arayot

IIRC, the story tells us that David sleeps with Uriah's wife, impregnates her, tries to get away with it and fails, commands his general to send the husband to be murdered, and after he dies, openly marries her.

Nathan the prophet appears before David and tells him a weird parable:

> "The rich man had very large flocks and herds, but the poor man had only one little ewe lamb that he had bought... One day, ... the rich man loath to take anything from his own flocks or herds to prepare a meal for the guest who had come to him; so he took the poor man’s lamb and prepared it for the man who had come to him.” [II_Samuel.12.2](http://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.12.2-4?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

I don't understand how the parable relates to what happened in the story to Uriah:

1. after all he was killed, he didn't know that David slept with his wife, and he definitely didn't care who took his wife post mortem.
2. if still alive, Uriah could have as many wives as he pleased, he apparently wasn't poor and could allow additional spouses.
3. the purpose of having a lamb is to finally consume it, which is totally different from having a wife. Even the parable says that the poor man "treated it like a daughter", not a wife. So the poor man would definitely prefer having four fine goats over his lousy ewe. This can not be said about a beloved wife (unless it's Job's sons, which God thinks can be replaced).
4. David's sin is clearly adultery, not even coveting (he did not beg Uriah to divorce her), but the parable speaks about theft. That's not even in the same category.
5. in the parable, the rich man had no feelings for the lamb and only used it to spare his own, which I can't think to attribute to David, as if he slept with another man's wife to spare himself sleeping with Michal (or other women). I suppose David had some feelings for her beyond plain lust.

How does Nathan's parable even remotely relate to David's deeds?

Comment: Adultery = stealing another’s wife in order to satisfy one’s desire (the guest of the parable)

Comment: @JoelK Thank you, please refer to #5. Did David desire to spare his wives? So in your interpretation, it was a one-night stand for David?

Comment: Al pi peshat I certainly think so. He only arranged to have her husband killed once he found out that she was pregnant and there was no way Uriah would believe that the child was his own

Comment: @JoelK Would you explain the whole story from the "one-night-stand" perspective? So he sees he bathing, desires her, sleeps with her, she tell him she's pregnant, but he doesn't want any relations with her and then...?

Comment: And then he realizes that when her husband comes back from war and finds her pregnant, the whole story is going to come out. So he tries getting the husband home quickly to sleep with his wife, so that he’ll think the child is his. When that doesn’t work, he arranges to have the husband killed.

Comment: Excellent question. ...Batsheva is the poor man. He ruined her life (who says she came willingly to him?). He took her husband's life and her dignity, and she will never be able to remarry. Had he chosen to placate his יצר הרע with one of his many wives, their lives would be mostly the same, even if he did so without their consent, as was likely the case with Batsheva. I admit I never thought of this before your question.

Comment: I think this is a good example of how a parable works. Of course there are differences, that's what makes it a parable. A lamb is less than two feet tall, and Batsheva...! But the prophet's point is clear: someone who had everything took from someone who had almost nothing, the only thing that mattered to him.

Comment: On your first point - there are many that think that Uriah definitely knew. This can be inferred from his mannerisms in the story, the way he continuously defies David and even refers to Yoav as his "lord". As such, I'm sure he would have, in fact, cared who married his wife post-mortem. On your second point, there's a reason a second wife is called in Tanach a "tzara". Not everyone wanted such a "tzara". On your third point, there's such a thing as sheep's milk.

Answer (score 2):

Although each separate question may perhaps have an answer, here is a thought from the Metzudas Dovid that perhaps removes the premise for some (or all) the questions;

> שני אנשים. על כי רצה שדוד בעצמו יפסוק הדין על עצמו, לזה אמר לו כאלו קובל לפניו על העול הנעשה בעיר, ושהוא יעשה משפט, וכשיפסוק הדין, אז יאמר לו אתה האיש ואף כי הרבה בדברים שאין ענין להם עם דבר דוד, אולם כוונתו היתה להעלים ביותר, לבל ירגיש דוד וישמור פיו מלפסוק הדין

So, yes there are deliberate inconsistencies in the parable, meant to throw Dovid off and not realize it’s about him.

Comment: This only emphasizes my question, since there's no (little) resemblance, why would David connect the parable to himself? He would say "a lame story but this has nothing to do with me.

Comment: Indeed he didn’t. He thought it was a real story and says the person should die and pay back 4 times etc. That’s when he told him that it was a parable and he was really the one who did something similar. He was then punished according to his judgement that he gave on the man in the parable.